# Setting beamer color in region between title bar and canvas

Tags: beamer, formatting, color

How does one control the color of the region between the title bar and the canvas in `beamer`? When the color of the background canvas is darkened there is a white bar between title and canvas. MWE follows along with image.

```
\documentclass[ ]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\title{Footer right}
\author{Footer left}

\begin{document}

{\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}

\section{First Section}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame Title}
  \color{white}{Remove white bar beneath title}
\end{frame}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the shadow of the frametitle fades to white. A quick solution would be to disable the shadow `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=false,shadow=false]`

Comment: There is somewhere a question on this side. The background colour in this question was cyan, but I absolutely can not find it. Sorry. I think I was from sometime late 2013 or so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Warsaw` uses the `shadow` outer theme which applies a shading after the frame title:

```
  \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@topshade}{\paperwidth}{%
    color(0pt)=(bg);
    color(4pt)=(black!50)}
```

One way to hide the shading is to redefine it so it matches your canvas background color:

```
  \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@topshade}{\paperwidth}{%
    color(0pt)=(black);
    color(4pt)=(black)}
```

this redefinition has to be done `\AtBeginDocument`. A complete example:

```
\documentclass[ ]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@topshade}{\paperwidth}{%
    color(0pt)=(black);
    color(4pt)=(black)}
}
\makeatother

\title{Footer right}
\author{Footer left}

\begin{document}

{\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}

\section{First Section}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame Title}
  \color{white}{White bar beneath title removed}
\end{frame}}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Notice that we are only hiding the shading: to remove it completely, one would have to make a local copy of `beamerouterthemeshadow.sty`, rename it and make some otther changes, since the shading is added with `\addtobeamertemplate`. Hiding the shading, however, is enough in my opinion.