# Remove shadow on frametitle,no theme used,personal customization

Tags: beamer, frame-title, shadows

```
\documentclass{beamer}    
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel} %βαζω την ελληνική γλώσσα...όλα θα γινουν ελληνικα αν δεν χρησιμοποιήσω το \en    
\usepackage{alphabeta}    
\usepackage{multicol}    
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}

\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}    
\author{\textlatin{e-M@th Team}}    
\usepackage{array,amsmath}    
\usepackage{amsthm}    
\usepackage{lipsum}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\definecolor{UniBlue}{RGB}{83,121,170}
\definecolor{frame}{RGB}{2,0,0}
\definecolor{LightBlue}{RGB}{153,187,255}
\definecolor{Warm}{RGB}{230,76,0}
\definecolor{BlockBackground}{RGB}{255,195,77}
\definecolor{BackgroundCanvas}{RGB}{255,221,153}    

\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=frame}    


\useoutertheme{shadow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\colorlet{titleleft}{red!75!black}
\colorlet{titleright}{Warm}    `

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titleright]{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperheight}{%
    color(0pt)=(titleleft);
    color(\paperwidth)=(titleright)}
\makeatother    `

\setbeamercolor*{author in head/foot}{fg=frame}
\setbeamercolor*{title in head/foot}{parent=palette secondary,bg=}
\setbeamercolor*{date in head/foot}{parent=palette tertiary,bg=}    

\setbeamercolor*{background canvas}{bg=BackgroundCanvas}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }%
    \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by 4pt%
    \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{20pt}
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
    \end{pgfpicture}
    \vskip-\beamer@tempdim%
    \box\beamer@tempbox%    
}%    `

\setbeamercolor*{block title}{fg=frame,bg=Warm} 
\setbeamercolor*{block body}{fg=frame,bg=BlockBackground} 

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}    
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]{}    

\date{}
\title{} 

\begin{document}    

    \begin{frame}{}
    \frametitle{Οι πραγματικοί αριθμοί}


    \begin{block}{παραδειγμα τιτλος}
        παραδειγμα προταση \newline τι \\ θα γινει \\ αν ειναι\\ πολυ \\ μεγαλο \\ το \\ παραδειγμα \\ ;; \\ ;; \\ ;;

    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

`

Comment: You question isn't clear to me. Please expand you question with a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that shows your problem and specify clearly what you want the output to look like.

Comment: I don't know how to mwe.
documentclass[beamer]
I've customized my frametitle with a horizontal shading.
I've set a background canvas color.
Between frametitle and background canvas there is a line of shadow from frametitle.
I want to eliminate that shadow,without eliminating the horizontal shading

Comment: To make a MWE, include one slide and your preamble with what you have done to customise things. Without seeing a simple document showing what you have done it is hard to help. What else have you got between `\documentclass{beamer}` and `\begin{document}`? And what code produces a simple slide showing your shading?

Comment: maybe now is more clear.I hope i didnt forget anything

Comment: This is my whole code.Customized headline,footline,boxes,colors,everything.

Comment: Does this question help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/255372/87678

Comment: Also, note that your shading from `cyan!75!black` to `RGB(83,121,170)` is *not* giving you the colours you expect. `cyan!75!black` is defined as a CMYK colour, but the shading is being output in RGB. You can test this by checking that a solid colour of `cyan!75!black` does not match the left edge of your gradient. I suggest you define `titleleft` in RGB to avoid this.